# How to output value from FileReader()

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I would like to know how I can get the value from a filereader() function.

Here is the code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
            var txt = e.target.result
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            var url_check = null;
            $.each(lines, function(n, data) {
                if (n == 0 && data != "") {
                    url_check = data
                }
            });
            $('#output_field').text(url_check);
        });
        console.log(url_check)
    });
});

function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file_input" type="file">
<div id="output_field"></div>
```

And I have this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: url_check is not defined

My goal is to return the variable `url_check` to be accessible outside the readFile function

I also tried declaring `url_check` outside the readFile function like :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        var url_check = null;
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
            var txt = e.target.result
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $.each(lines, function(n, data) {
                if (n == 0 && data != "") {
                    url_check = data
                }
            });
            $('#output_field').text(url_check);
        });
        console.log(url_check)
    });
});

function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file_input" type="file">
<div id="output_field"></div>
```

Comment: @Islam what is `const fs = require('fs');` ?

Comment: The problem is just that the `readFile()` function succeeds AFTER the `console.log`, thus it can't display your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are declaring the `url_check` variable inside `$(document).ready(function() ...`, it means it is going to be accessible only there. A solution would be to declare the parameter globally, so that any changes from the function would be still visible. If you want to do something with the variable after it is assigned, you'd have to call the function there, immediately. Calling it before might result in null results, since the file wasn't processed yet. See the jsfiddle below. I tested it any it does what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_input').on('change', function(e) {
    readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
      var txt = e.target.result
      var lines = txt.split("\n");
      
      if (lines && lines.length > 0)
        url_check = lines[0];
      
      $('#output_field').text(url_check);
      console.log(url_check);
      callbackPrint();
    });
  });
});

var url_check = null;

function readFile(file, onLoadCallback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function callbackPrint() {
  console.log("From testPrint: " + url_check);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file_input" type="file">
<div id="output_field"></div>
```

Comment: I tested the code and still doesn't work, the function `testPrint` output `null`

Comment: @executable what files are you testing it with? I just selected a .txt file with some random text and I got the first line from it.

Comment: Yes but testPrint output only `From testPrint: null`

Comment: If OP just wants to get the first line, he can just use `url_check = lines[0]`. Also, @executable do you need access to the file's first line outside the function?

Comment: @Terry you are right; I modified the code; executable, I asked what file did you use to test the code (what format; binary? text? are you sure it's not empty?).

Comment: I used a text file. @Terry Yep

Comment: @executable [Image proof](https://i.imgur.com/sVA1xW8.png) that it works here. What browser do you test it on?

Comment: Yes I know it works like that but if you `console.log()` outside the readFile function you get a null value. I would like to make the variable `url_check` available everywhere

Comment: @executable can you check the code again, please? I forgot to actually call the test function, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is run asynchronously you should consider using a promise or a callback function to resolve/return the url_check in order to access it outside of the readFile function.

If you just want to log the value of url_check out `console.log(url_check)` must be placed inside the readFile